# ¿Cómo poner los null hacia la derecha del array?

Tags: java, java-8

Tengo dos arrays de String, el primero puede o no tener cadenas y el segundo esta vació, y quiero copiar el primero en el segundo pero dejando los huecos vacíos a la derecha y los que tienen cadena a la izquierda.

```java
String[] s = new String[5];
String[] p = new String[5];
s[3] = "hola";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));

for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length - 1; j++) {
        if (s[j] == null) {
            p[i] = s[j + 1];
        }
    }
}

/*
Array s:
[null, null, null, hola, null]
Array p:
[null, null, null, null, null]

Resultado que espero:
Array p:
[hola, null, null, null, null]

Resultado que me da:
[hola, hola, hola, hola, hola]
*/
```

Entiendo el por que me esta dando este resultado, sin embargo ya hice otras pruebas y aun no conseguí el resultado esperado que es separar a la derecha los null y a la izquierda las cadenas.
El tamaño del array s da igual a si como su contenido, puede tener tamaño de 20 y varias cadenas por el medio separadas por sitios vacíos(null). El resultado final tiene que ser un array del mismo tamaño pero haciendo la separación mencionada

Comment: La pregunta está al revés. Debería ser: ¿Cómo poner los `null` a la derecha? La verdad si el primer arreglo por defecto tiene `null`, no necesitas desplazar nada porque el arreglo dos ya tiene los `null`. Solo debes enfocarte en desplazar hacia la izquierda las cadenas que tenga el arreglo uno.

Comment: @MrDave1999 tienes razón me equivoque en el nombre del titulo, tiene que ser como lo dices, desplazar los null a la derecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Algoritmo:**

- Recorres el arreglo `s` a través de un bucle.
- Verificar si `X` elemento del arreglo `s` no contiene un `null`.
- Si la condición se cumple, pues agregamos la referencia del objeto hacia la izquierda.
- Se debe incrementar la variable `j` para saber en que posición hay que añadir la referencia.

```java
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {   
        int j = 0;
        String[] s = new String[5];
        String[] p = new String[5];
        s[3] = "hola";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        {
            if(s[i] != null)
            {
                p[j] = s[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));
    }
}
```

Resultado por pantalla:

```java
[hola, null, null, null, null]
```

Si tuviéramos `20` elementos, el algoritmo funcionaría igual.